# What does it means, Spark’s internal Fair Scheduler lets long-lived applications define queues

Tags: apache-spark, scheduler

I am trying to understand Spark's Job Scheduling and got this point in the [Learning Spark](https://books.google.pl/books?id=2eptBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA129&dq=Spark%20provides%20a%20mechanism%20through%20configurable%20intra-application%20scheduling%20policies.%20Spark%E2%80%99s%20internal%20Fair%20Scheduler%20lets%20long-lived%20application&pg=PA129#v=onepage&q=Spark%20provides%20a%20mechanism%20through%20configurable%20intra-application%20scheduling%20policies.%20Spark%E2%80%99s%20internal%20Fair%20Scheduler%20lets%20long-lived%20application&f=false),

> "Spark provides a mechanism through configurable intra-application
>   scheduling policies. Spark’s internal Fair Scheduler lets long-lived
>   applications define queues for prioritizing scheduling of tasks"

Could you please give me bit more details on this?

Comment: have you Google'd this or looked at Spark's own documentation on the Fair Scheduler?

for example [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application)

What is it exactly about the statement that you don't understand from the book you referenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in a [fair scheduler documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#fair-scheduler-pools) you can maintain multiple pools, each with its own scheduling policy, minimal (`minShare`) and relative (`weight`) resource allocation. The last one is described as follows:

> If you give a specific pool a weight of 2, for example, it will get 2x more resources as other active pools. Setting a high weight such as 1000 also makes it possible to implement priority between pools—in essence, the weight-1000 pool will always get to launch tasks first whenever it has jobs active.